# Shiny slider works for numeric ranges, but not for dates

Tags: shiny

Shiny sliders don't seem to be working for me with dates, but they work fine with numbers.  This works:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range", "Range", min = 0, max = 10, value = c(2, 4))                                                           )                   
shinyApp(ui, function(...) {})
```

[Screenshot of slider with numeric values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyD4m.png)

This doesn't:

```
 library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range", "Range", min = as.Date("2021-01-01"), max = as.Date("2021-12-31"), value = c(as.Date("2021-02-02"), as.Date("2021-03-03")))
)                             
shinyApp(ui, function(...) {})
```

It just produces a blank box:

[Screenshot of blank box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IJ6K.png)

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908808/how-to-sliderinput-for-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(sliderInput(
  inputId = "range",
  label = "Range",
  min = as.Date("2021-01-01"),
  max = as.Date("2021-12-31"),
  value = c(as.Date("2021-02-02"), as.Date("2021-03-03"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Great - thanks - this is currently not working for me on debian bullseye, but there must be something wrong with my setup, I will investigate...